# Parsing through SAS array, macro variables

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, do-loops

I want to create an array which stores the names of variables. Then index into the array and pass to a function. So far I have the following:

```
%let variables = cat dog lion sheep;

data _null_;
  array a_vars[*] &variables;
  do i = 1 to dim(a_vars);
    some_function(a_vars[i],i);
  end;
run;
```

I'm running into a problem with assigning the variables to the array and then indexing the array in the function to do: `some_function(cat, 1)` or `some_function(dog,2)` etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with the vname() function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do.  As mentioned you can use VNAME to find the name of the i*th* array element.  Is that really what you need?

```
26         data _null_;
27            array a_vars[*] &variables;
28            length name $32;
29            do i = 1 to dim(a_vars);
30               name = vname(a_vars[i]);
31               put (i name) (=);
32               end;
33            run;

i=1 name=cat
i=2 name=dog
i=3 name=lion
i=4 name=sheep
```